# Add pyspark script as AWS step

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a pyspark script to read an xml file(present in S3). I need to add this as a step in aws. I have used the following command

```
aws emr add-steps — cluster-id <cluster_id> — steps Type=spark,Name=POI,Args=[ — deploy-mode,cluster, — master,yarn, — conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true,<s3 location of pyspark script>],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE
```

I have downloaded the spark-xml jar to the master node during bootstrap and its present under

> /home/hadoop

location. Also in the python script I have included

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Project').set("spark.jars", "/home/hadoop/spark-xml_2.11-0.4.1.jar").set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/home/hadoop/spark-xml_2.11-0.4.1.jar")
```

But still its showing

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o56.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.xml. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

Comment: path for `file:///home/hadoop...`

Answer (score 1):

You have set master as **yarn** and deploy-mode as **cluster**. That means your spark driver will be in one of CORE nodes.
Anyway, EMR by default is configured to create Application master on one of the CORE node and application master will have the driver in it.

Please refer this [article](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cdh_ig_running_spark_on_yarn.html) for more info.

So you have to put your jar in **all** CORE nodes (Not in MASTER) and refer the file `file:///home/hadoop/spark-xml_2.11-0.4.1.jar` in this manner.

Or there is better way to put it in HDFS (Lets say under `hdfs:///user/hadoop`) and refer that `hdfs:///user/hadoop/spark-xml_2.11-0.4.1.jar`